# ICollection<string> to string[]

Tags: c#, generics, collections, .net-2.0

I have a object of type `ICollection<string>`.  What is the best way to convert to `string[]`.

How can this be done in .NET 2?
How can this be done cleaner in later version of C#, perhaps using LINQ in C# 3?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could use the following snippet to convert it to an ordinary array:

```
string[] array = new string[collection.Count];
collection.CopyTo(array, 0);
```

That should do the job :)

Comment: do i need to initialize the array with the right size first .. 
cant i just do this: 
            string[] futures = new string[] {};
            FutureFVDictionary.Keys.CopyTo(futures, 0); ;

Comment: The array must first be initialized to the correct size - otherwise CopyTo will fail with an ArgumentException.

Comment: with List<String>(mycoll).ToArray() you don't have to worry about size.

Comment: @AdrianoKF The first line should be `string[] array = new string[collection.Count];`, since `ICollection` has a [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s3kzhec.aspx) property.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using C# 3.0 and .Net framework 3.5, you should be able to do:

```
ICollection<string> col = new List<string>() { "a","b"};
string[] colArr = col.ToArray();
```

of course, you must have "using System.Linq;" at the top of the file

Comment: Also List<T> has a ToArray method since .NET 2.0, so if you're using List<T> you don't need System.Linq

Comment: He asked for ICollection<string>

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion

Answer (score 7):

In the (trivial) case of `ICollection<String>`, use ToArray:

```
String[] GetArray(ICollection<String> mycoll)
{
    return mycoll.ToArray<String>();
}
```

EDIT: with .Net 2.0, you can return the array with an extra `List<String>`:

```
String[] GetArray(ICollection<String> mycoll)
{
    List<String> result = new List<String>(mycoll);
    return result.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: The compiler can infer the type argument, so mycoll.ToArray() would be fine, without needing the <string> part.

Comment: The List<T>.ToArray method uses an array copy, so doing the array copy directly would be the better option than creating a list, which is another object.

Comment: List<String>(mycoll).ToArray() abstracts the array creation and copying details.